Detect S Pen clicks in Termux?
Is it possible to detect Samsung Galaxy Ultra's S Pen button clicks in Termux?
I'm rooted if that helps

Possibly related existing open issue: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1744 Just be aware that Samsung S Pen SDK exists for Android apps to specifically support S Pen features.
